# solr no results found after indexing

Tags: solr

Am using DataImportHandle to import sql data to solr.

am getting

Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 121 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
Requests: 1, Fetched: 121, Skipped: 0, Processed: 121

after import

when  i query `q=*:*`  am getting 0 results

01*:*xml

Comment: Use Luke to se what exactly have Solr indexed.

Comment: Did you perform a commit or checked the commit option so that the documents are available for search ?

Comment: @luke i cant see remote index on uke

Comment: @jayendra while writing schema i have added commit there ,

Comment: Do you mean AutoCommit ? Can you add your schema.xml ? When you data import do you check the Commit option ?

Comment: @jayendra thanks , checked autocommit it shows result now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you data import check the Commit option

Credit :  @Jayendra https://stackoverflow.com/users/950178/jayendra

Answer (score 0):

Try the query using `q=*:*` That is the standard search all fields for all values query.